# Memoize callback function

Tags: javascript, memoization

I was trying this memoization on

```
function getData(n, m, callback){
    callback(n+m);
};
let memoizedData = memoize(getData);
console.log(memoizedData(5, 4, (result)=>{})) // 9;
```

I want to cache the result i,e, 9 so whenever next call happens it takes from cache.
I understand memoization if getData would have return n+m instead of putting to the callback.
Any help will be appreciated.

Edits: **Want to implement this via vanillaJs.**
Edited the above question for more clarity

```
function getData(n, m, callback){
    callback(n+m);
};
let memoizedData = memoize(getData);
memoizedData(5, 4, (result)=>{console.log(result)}) // 9;
memoizedData(5, 4, (result)=>{console.log(result)}) // 9 - returned from cache
```

Comment: Any attempt at writing the function `memoize`? What is the problem you have while trying? Why do you expect `console.log` to print anything useful when `getData` doesn't return anything, but instead calls a callback?

Comment: I did not exactly understand, But are you looking on how to implement memoization ?

Comment: Yes I attempted it but got stuck at callback thingy. @trincot

Comment: yes memoization with this callback thing. I was able to implement the same with getSomeData returning n+m. @GermanOchea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking for an implementation of `memoize`. As to your `console.log`: this is strange, since the result is not *returned*, but passed as an argument to a callback. So you should actually print within that callback. You could even pass `console.log` *as* callback.

For the implementation of `memoize`, I will assume that the function to memoize will always have a callback as last parameter.

First, `memoize` should return a function which accept the same arguments as the function that is memoized.

The idea is to maintain a Map, keyed by the arguments that are passed to the function (excluding the callback argument), and with the corresponding result. One way to build the key is to form the JSON representation of the arguments.

When `memoize` is called, and the arguments form a key that is already present in the map, then call the callback with the corresponding value from the map. If not present, then call the function with the same set of arguments, except for the callback. Let the callback be a function that stores the result in the map, and then passes the result on to the callback that was passed to `memoize`.

Here is how you could write it:

```js
function memoize(func) {
    let map = new Map; // for memoization
    return function(...args) {
        let callback = args.pop(); // last argument must be a function
        let key = JSON.stringify(args);
        let result = map.get(key);
        if (result !== undefined) {
            console.log(`getting result from map.get('${key}')`);
            return callback(result);
        }
        console.log(`calling ${func.name}(${args.join(", ")}, callback)`);
        func(...args, result => {
            console.log(`writing result with map.set('${key}', ${result})`);
            map.set(key, result);
            callback(result);
        });
    }
}

function getData(n, m, callback){
    callback(n+m);
}
let memoizedData = memoize(getData);


memoizedData(5, 4, console.log) // 9 calling getData;
memoizedData(5, 4, console.log) // 9 from memory;
```

Note that this:

```
memoizedData(5, 4, console.log)
```

...is just "short" for:

```
memoizedData(5, 4, (result) => console.log(result))
```

The only difference is that there is an extra wrapper function around `console.log`, but practically there is no real difference.

Comment: Ok I have understood a lot from this answer and honestly I was wanting something like this but what if my memoizedData will be ```
memoizedData(5, 4, (result)=>{console.log("result", result)})     
```

Comment: You want `memoizedData` to be recursive? Can you describe more what you are looking for here? Are you just talking about the last line where you call `memoizedData` with a more elaborate callback argument? Sure that works. Do you see any problem? See edit to my answer.

Comment: Oh yes I have understood this will work, Thanks a lot @trincot. Thank you so so much.

Comment: Just curious about as you mentioned recursive `memoizedData `, do you happen to come across some problem and would like to share. @trincot

Comment: No, it was just how you phrased your first comment above. It confused me, as if you were *defining* `memoizedData` in terms of itself. But then I realized you were just talking about how to *call* it, not *define* it.

Comment: Oh ok Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If your asking how to implement memoization you may implement it like this

```
import { useMemo, useCallback } from 'react';

export default function Index() {
  const getData = useCallback((n, m, callback) => callback(n + m), []);

  let memoizedData = useMemo(() => getData(5, 4, (result) => result), [
    getData,
  ]);
  console.log(memoizedData);
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing but I forgot to mention that I was trying to solve this via vanillaJs. Added a edit now